# Sum over different sheets of a particular value of a field in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel workbook which contains the data of a time report in the following form:

```
Code    Start Time     End Time    Total Time
5.3     10:30          12:00       1:30
2.1     2:00           4:00        2:00
...
```

I have a sheet for each workday which is filled in the showed form. At the end of the month I'd like to have a report of the number of hours invested for each code. I am aware this could be potentially done with a VBA script that takes for each code the number of hours worked (`Total Time`) and sum it up, displaying it in the end of the month sheet. I was wondering if this could be done with a worksheet function inside the end of the month sheet, which looks like this:

```
Code    Total hours in this month
1.1     0
1.2     1:00
1.3     35:45
...
```

Hope the question is clear enough.

Thank you!

EDIT: To avoid confusion, let me specify that the codes in any given way are inputted in no order: I cannot simply sum every value in a given cell in every sheet, but I need to pick the value(s) associated to a code in each sheet to compute the total. Every code may appear more than once in each workday sheet, and they may be in a different place for every sheet.

Answer (score 1):

you can sum over sheets.
=Sum(start:end!G20) adds all values in cell G20 from sheet start to sheet end.

Greets
Kevin

Comment: so many people are unaware of 3D functions, once mastered you can even use VLOOKUP in a '3D' way, nice answer

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for your reply! For each code in the end of the month sheet I need to sum only the time values associated to a specific code. In any given day I can have codes in different places (depending on what happened on that day), so your solution is infeasible unfortunately (I can't have all values of, say, "5.1" in cell, say, "G20" every day).

Comment: @User91504 I looked for the VLOOKUP function and I could indeed use it to lookup for all the occurrences of said code (1.1, 1.2, ...) but it seems I cannot lookup for a specific code in the entire workbook...

Comment: Maybe you could use the consolidate function described here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b